# 2.8/Grease Pencil. How to flip a stroke horizontally?

Tags: grease-pencil

I only need to do this for a few strokes. Unfortunately, the Mirror modifier is being applied to the whole drawing. 
Thanks guys,

DPC

Answer (score 1):

In Edit mode, select the strokes you want to flip and scale them in -1. Thanks to dan2 from blenderartists.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>M</kbd> then press  <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or  <kbd>Z</kbd> to flip in *Edit Mode*.